# Line Breaks not showing at the beginning of the text on a .rdl Report (sql server reporting services)

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, report, rdl

I'm printing my reports to PDF from a .rdl report, I have different fields on it and it all comes out from the Database of course, the funny problem I have now is that when one of the fields got 1 or 2 line breaks at the beginning  of the field it just suppress them!, however if I add any character before the line breaks, even a simple "." (dot) then the line breaks are there just as they are supposed to be.

I'm trying to fix this, any ideas?,

I need to have those line breaks to align different columns, and when this happens the columns won't align correctly.

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this before, but when I just tried to reproduce the problem, I wasn't able to.

Make sure that your text cells are not set to Markup type: HTML. This would trim whitespace. They should be set to None.

I just correctly prefixed fields with line breaks both from a SQL query (`Char(13) + Char(10) + FieldName as TestField2`) and in a SSRS calculated field (`Environment.NewLine + Fields!FieldName.Value`)